# Calling a sql server stored procedure with output parameter when using Simple.Data

Tags: sql-server, simple.data

Using Simple.Data, I would like to get the result from an output parameter in a stored procedure. Let's say I have the following SP (disregard the uselessness of it):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProc]
    @InParam int,
    @OutParam int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @OutParam = @InParam * 10
END
```

When I call it with Simple.Data, I use the following code.

```
var db = Database.Open();

int outParam;
var result = db.TestProc(42, out outParam);

Console.WriteLine(outParam); // <-- == 0
Console.WriteLine(result.OutputValues["OutParam"]); // <-- == 420
```

It feels like outParam should contain the value, and not the OutputValues dictionary. So my question is: Is there a nicer way to get the result from OutParam in this particular case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `out` parameters are not supported by the dynamic binding infrastructure used by Simple.Data, as they are not supported in all CLR languages.

I am open to suggestions for better syntax, though.

Comment: if you could call it without the need of sending outParam as an argument it would look nice. Just db.TestProc(42); (I have no idea if it's even possible...)

Comment: If you change the stored procedure and supply a default value for the output parameter, you don't need to pass it.

`CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc(@Answer INT, @Question INT = NULL OUTPUT)`

then

`db.TestProc(42);`

will work fine.